# Filter a multidimensional array by date between two dates

Tags: php, arrays, filter

I have array like this:

```
arr=[
   627=[
   'lead_data'=>['name'=>'Name1',  'date'=>'2019-04-09']
   ],
   500=[
   'lead_data'=>['name'=>'Name2',  'date'=>'2018-05-07']
   ],
   534=[
  'lead_data'=>['name'=>'Name3',  'date'=>'2019-07-10']
   ],
  100=[
  'lead_data'=>['name'=>'Name4',  'date'=>'2019-05-12']
  ],

 ]
```

How can I filter this array where date is between 2019-05-01 and 2019-07-12.
So in result there will be elements with ids 534 and 100.
Or date is >= 2019-07-05 or date is <= 2019-01-01 ?

I know there is array_filter function, but cant understand how to use it in thus case? Please help, thanks

Comment: where's the code?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would to just iterate over your data like so:

```
 <?php
        $begin = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("2019-05-01"));
        $end = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("2019-07-12"));

        foreach($array as $key => $data) 
        {
           $date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($$data['date']));
           if (($$data > $begin) && ($date < $end)){
               unset($array[$key]);
           }
        }
        var_dump($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Always make sure you check out [official documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-filter.php) on php.net because it usually have tons of examples and very thorough explanations.

In your case you can compare dates as strings (since they are in Y-m-d format and comparing them alphabetically will do the trick):

```
$filtered = array_filter($arr, function ($item) {
    return ($item['lead_data']['date'] > '2019-05-01') && ($item['lead_data']['date'] < '2019-07-12');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

By using `array_filter()`, and using the `use` keyword, you can supply variables into the filter - this can be the start- and end-dates for your limits.

When using `array_filter()`, the data will remain in the array if the `return` value inside the callback is true, otherwise it will be removed. So then compare the dates, and see if they are greater than `$from`, and less than `$to`.

```php
$from = '2019-05-01';
$to = '2019-07-12';
$result = array_filter($arr, function ($v) use ($from, $to) {
    return $v['lead_data']['date'] > $from && $v['lead_data']['date'] < $to;
});
print_r($result);
```

- Live demo at https://3v4l.org/Cmt8H